# AWS API Gateway: How To Inform API Users They Are Close To Their Usage Limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a REST API with usage plans configured on AWS API Gateway.

I want to send an email to the users of the API if they have used > 90% of their plan. What would be the best way to do it?

Is it possible to add the usage information for an API key into the header of the request that comes through API Gateway to the server?

Alternatively, I could use API Gateway REST API, I suppose. I am afraid though that it won't scale to the level of invoke requests against deployed APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cloudwatch to store the number of api calls on the bases of apiid and set an alert on that which will trigger an email

Comment: I cannot create an alert without knowing the API key beforehand, can I? It means that for each user, I need to create an alert manually which is not scalable. Am I missing something?

Comment: Enable "Custom Access Logging" to get logs in cloud watch logs ...map this to cloud watch metrics and set alert. If this seems an overkill then u can always create a scheduled Lambda function which calls API gateway and get usage metrics and store trigger state in dynamo DB so that you send email once only https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-usage.html